# Can't Access Dropdown In Iframe Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Thank you for taking a look at my question, I appreciate your help.

I looked around at the available answers and none of them seem to work for me. Other answers seem to deal with switching to an iframe, which I do successfully (otherwise it would crash sooner, right?), then I can't select a dropdown menu in that iframe.

Some of the approaches I tried:

[Unable to click on dropdown within iframe - Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59108289/unable-to-click-on-dropdown-within-iframe-selenium-python)

[Can't access dropdown select using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356550/cant-access-dropdown-select-using-selenium-in-python)

[Python Selenium - Cant Click on Button (iFrame Solved !)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813415/python-selenium-cant-click-on-button-iframe-solved)

For some reason the element isn't there - I tried using wait statements (both sleep and EC.waits) but that also didn't work. When I observe the program run, I can see that the driver successfully loads the iframe and the elements are selectable, so I think it may be a misunderstanding in how you access iframe elements.

Here is the code, you'll notice it is behind a login block, I don't know what I can do in this case to help people get to that point, but I have shared all the html and code I can think of and can share more upon request:

```
def clear_wardrobe():
    """Clears the user's wardrobe so that they have no items listed"""
    try:
        # Initialize
        log_in()

        # Fetch the number of items on the page and loop through all of them.
        while True:
            driver.get("https://www.grailed.com/users/myitems")
            time.sleep(2)
            item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"wardrobe\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div[2]/img")
            item.click()
            time.sleep(3)

            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[9]/div[2]/span/a")
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

            time.sleep(0.5)
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"Listing--Actions\"]/div/div[1]")
            element.click()
            time.sleep(1)

            # switch to specific iframe and select "Sold Elsewhere option" - ISSUE IS HERE
            frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@title,'Optimizely Internal Frame')]")
            driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
            select_box = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("reason"))
            select_box.select_by_visible_text("Sold Elsewhere")
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']").click()

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Something went wrong in clearWardrobe()")
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Here is the page with dropdown - I want to select sold elsewhere [image]

And here is the error message:

```
Something went wrong in clearWardrobe()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomas.mclaughlin/Documents/GitHub/WardrobeWizard2/scripts/core.py", line 110, in clear_wardrobe
    select_box = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("reason"))
  File "/Users/thomas.mclaughlin/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/Users/thomas.mclaughlin/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Users/thomas.mclaughlin/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/thomas.mclaughlin/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="reason"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to be in the iframe.

Comment: it's just a modal div there... don't need to switch to the frame.

Comment: @pcalkins I started these shenanigans because I couldn't select the element on the modal - that led me to think it was an iframe issue, I will try to recreate the first issue and update this post.

Comment: @pcalkins Wow, I am really embarassed, sorry about that - I can't believe I didn't do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the element was in a modal and not an iframe so the question is flawed.